# How to check if date is valid with 3 integers? (Method returning bool)

Tags: c#, methods, properties, boolean

I'm trying to make a method which checks if day, month and year are correctly inserted. Method returns TRUE if date is okay and FALSE if date is NOT okay. **Problem: Code always returns false.**

```
const int max_year = 2100;
const int min_year = 1900;

static bool CheckDate(int d, int m, int y)   
{
    if (d < 1 || d > 31)
    {
        if (m < 1 || m > 12)
        {
            if (y < min_year || y > max_year)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then I'm checking the date in the property like:

```
public int Day
{
    get
    {
        return day;
    }
    set
    {
        if (CheckDate(dan, mesec, year) == true)
        {
            day = value;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Day is incorrect!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside from your actual problem, what if I told it to validate April 31st? There are better ways to do this where you don't need to roll your own solution.

Comment: Works fine with CheckDate(1,1,2019)?

Comment: This is just a simple example. I'm going to add other validations later. For now I'm only checking if day is between 1 and 31, month between 1 and 12, year between 1900 and 2100. @BrootsWaymb

Comment: DateTime can already do this, so there is no need to reimplement it. You could use e.g. `static bool CheckDate(int d, int m, int y) { return min_year <= y && y <= max_year && DateTime.TryParse($"{y}-{m}-{d}", out _); }`.

Comment: the way i see it, nothing's wrong. except, as Broots have said, this would return a false-positive result on non-valid date combination, i.e.: Feb 30, 2010

Comment: Doesn't work @RistoM

Comment: If you do `CheckDate(5, 2000, 123456)`  it will return `true` because, once your d is between 1 and 31 you always return true. Same for `CheckDate(0, 5, 2000)`

Comment: @RokŠekoranja it returns true with `CheckDate(1,1,2019)`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fv8qiR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to point out a possible bug and/or bad design in your property setter (this can be reason why your "*Code always returns false*").

If you look closely, you see that `CheckDate` is always called with parameters `dan`, `mesec` and `year`. As you know, `value` is the value to be setted (`Day = 1`, or `Day = 500`), but it is not part of `CheckDate`-call.

If this is your purpose, I can say it is very bad design. You should call `CheckDate` straight in your code, not with *almost-side-effects-looking* property setter.

```
public int Day
{
    get
    {
        return day;
    }
    set
    {
        // Why this?
        if (CheckDate(dan, mesec, year) == true)
        {
            day = value;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Day is incorrect!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As simple as possible, just convert your numbers to a string and then do a DateTime.TryParseExact with the format yyyyMMdd

```
bool CheckDate(int y, int m, int d)
{

    string t = $"{y:D4}{m:D2}{d:D2}";
    return DateTime.TryParseExact(t, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None,  out DateTime dt);
}
```

Of course, if you want to limit the valid years you can add a simple logic to test the *y* variable as you already do now before building the string to parse.

```
if (y < min_year || y > max_year)
    return false;
....
```

Comment: You don't need the roundtrip of creating a string and parsing it again. You can just try to create a `new DateTime(y, m, d)` which will throw on any invalid date.

Comment: No that's would be wrong because you will drive code using exceptions. TryParse will avoid a costly exception. This will be a lot faster with invalid dates.

Comment: @derpirscher TryParseExact avoids throwing an exception though and you don't want to throw exceptions on purpose.

Comment: In performance point of view, throwing exception is expensive to do. Good practice to avoid it in "normal" validation logic. EDIT: 3 similar comments simultaneously :)

Comment: Instead of returning the result of the TryParseExact, catch the result in a variable like this: var result = DateTime.TryParseExact . . . . And if it is false, return it but if it is true, check that the date is between January 1st 1900 and December 31st 2100

Comment: I had somewhere in my head that the `.TryParse()` methods do the exception handling internally. But seems I was wrong ...

Answer (score -1):

Or you could do this :

```
static bool CheckDate(int d, int m, int y) 
{
   try
   {
      // This will throw an exception if the year, month or day are invalid
      var temp = new DateTime(y, m, d);
      return true;
   }
   except
   {
     return false;
   }
}
```